# How to handle UTF-8 characters when reading a file in SAS?

Tags: csv, utf-8, sas

How to handle UTF-8 characters when reading a file in SAS?

Such as spanish characters like ó í é á among other special characters within UTF-8 so it doesn't display garbage strings like

**Ã©** instead of **é**

Comment: Nice q&a, but you might want to include some additional information.  It looks like you're running this in Enterprise Guide, right?  And you may need to verify that your SAS is running in Unicode compatibility mode for this to work completely.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to achieve this is **Right click your file's metadata step -> Properties**

[image]

**File Parameters -> Advanced**

[image]

Now type **UTF-8** in the encoding options. Press OK and it should be enabled for that file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From [SAS Documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/nlsref/69741/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0utx4w7x4exijn1wt7pk0srrxz5.htm):

To specify which encoding to use when reading the external file, specify the `ENCODING=` option:

```
libname myfiles  'SAS data-library';        
filename extfile 'external-file' encoding="utf-8";

data myfiles.unicode;                                                                                                                           
   infile extfile;                                                                                                     
   input Make $ Model $ Year;                                                                                                           
run;
```